# error while executing insert triggers

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

```
DROP TRIGGER EPI_BOREHOLE_INI;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EPI_BOREHOLE_INI
INSTEAD of Insert ON EPI_BOREHOLE for each row
DECLARE
V_ID    number(10);
V_USER  varchar2(100);
BEGIN
if (:new.UBHI is null or :new.NAME is null or) then
    Raise_Application_Error(-20101, 'Insert failed. The key values of BOREHOLE(UBHI, NAME) cannot be null');
    end if;
begin
    select BOREHOLE_ID.nextval into V_ID from dual;
    SELECT USER INTO V_USER FROM DUAL;
    INSERT INTO EPI_BOREHOLE (ID, UBHI, NAME, INSERT_DATE ,INSERT_NAME, UPDATE_DATE,UPDATE_NAME) VALUES (V_ID,:NEW.UBHI, :NEW.NAME, SYSDATE, V_USER, SYSDATE, V_USER);
end;
END;
```

Comment: If you can't be bothered to explain HOW this isn't working, we can't be bothered to try and GUESS what the problem might be.

Comment: when i click on "run" ...a new window opened and it asked for "enter bind variables"

Comment: all my syntax are correct

Comment: `:new.ubhi`? That's a placeholder, not a reference to the new record being inserted. take off the `:`.

Comment: if i removed the If statement .then also error comes out to be same

Comment: ORA-00911: invalid character........error

Comment: What tool are you using? What is popping up windows and asking for stuff?

Comment: it worked sir.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see little error in your code: Please see below:

```
if (:new.UBHI is null or :new.NAME is null or) then  <-- An additional OR written.
```

remove it and try or put one more condition.

Comment: a new window open and ask to enter the bind variables

Comment: ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EPI_BOREHOLE_INI INSTEAD of Insert ON test for each row DECLARE V_ID number(10); V_USER varchar2(100); BEGIN if (:new.A is null or :new.B is null ) then Raise_Application_Error(-20101, 'Insert failed. The key values of BOREHOLE(UBHI, NAME) cannot be null'); end if; begin select 1 into V_ID from dual; INSERT INTO EPI_BOREHOLE (ID, UBHI, NAME, INSERT_DATE ,INSERT_NAME, UPDATE_DATE,UPDATE_NAME) VALUES (V_ID,:NEW.A, :NEW.B, SYSDATE, USER, SYSDATE, USER); end; END; ---- This is working

Comment: You can always upvote if the solutions works and repost you corrected code for reference to others.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any issue with the code.
Try doing

> SET DEFINE OFF

Comment: Go to command window..
SQL > SET DEFINE OFF
SQL > --run your trigger block here

Comment: Normally SET DEFINE OFF is for substitution variables. The OP hasn't thought to mention what tool he is using though, so anything's possible.